# Is there a benefit to aggregating all of the answers to a question into the top-voted answer?

Tags: discussion

Is there a benefit to aggregating all of the answers to a question into the top-voted answer as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-can-i-do-calculations-at-the-command-line)?

On one hand it concentrates the answers in one place, but on the other hand the vast majority of the up-votes go to a single answer and user, based on information provided by other users.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think such answers really add much. Often that's a sign that the question isn't that great a fit for Stack Exchange.

When a collated answer seems appropriate, I think it's good form to mark  it community wiki (something I'm generally opposed to for questions, by the way), *unless* the person doing the aggregation provides meaningful commentary relating the different answers to each other.